# How can I start a fragment from an activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am having trouble working with fragment in android. I have an activity that contains a `listview` and a `button` when I click on item I want to go to another fragment that contains details of this item selected, I've used :

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                        long id) {

                    // on récupère la HashMap contenant les infos de notre item
                    // (titre, description, img)
                    HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) maListViewPerso
                            .getItemAtPosition(position);

                    // Create fragment and give it an argument specifying the article it should show
                    ProfileEvent even= new ProfileEvent();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("key", map.get("idunique"));
                Log.d("laad",map.get("idunique"));
                    even.setArguments(bundle);


                     getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container3, even  )
                        .commit();
```

I don't know what to do data is passed to the fragment but I can't get the view,my logcat indicates nothing is wrong.wish u could help me

Comment: Is the container visible in your ui? (R.id.container3)

Comment: yes, the container of the layout of my activity is visible .I don't know where is my fault ?? can you plz tell what i am doing wrong

Comment: Can you post your layout file?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container3"
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

     <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Search events.."
            android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
            android:paddingRight="30dp" />......

Comment: this is my layout not the entire file I have button and a listview

Answer (score 0):

Am I right that you are trying to use a linear layout as a container for your fragment? As container for fragments you must use a frame layout.

Answer (score 0):

Dude your code

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("key", map.get("idunique"));

is correct. Now what you do is get that string value in fragment like.

Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
myValue = bundle.getString("key");